# Splunk 7.2.9.1 Universal forwarder on SUSE Linux12.4 not communicating and forwarding logs to Indexer after certain period of time

Tags: splunk, suse

I have noticed Splunk 7.2.9.1 Universal forwarder on SUSE Linux12.4 is not communicating to deployment server and forwarding logs to indexer after certain period of time. "splunkd" process appears to be running while this issue persists. 
I have to restart UFW for it to resume communication to deployment and forward logs. But this will again stop communication after certain period of time.

I cannot see any specific logs in splunkd.log while this issue occurs.
However, i noticed below message from watchdog.log

06-16-2020 11:51:09.055 +0200 ERROR Watchdog - No response received from IMonitoredThread=0x7f24365fdcd0 within 8000 ms. Looks like thread name='Shutdown' is busy !? Starting to trace with 8000 ms interval.

Can somebody help to understand what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Known Issue.  From the 7.2.9.1 release notes:

> Universal Forwarders stop sending data repeatedly throughout the day
>
> Workaround: In limits.conf, try changing file_tracking_db_threshold_mb
>   in the [inputproc] stanza to a lower value.
>   I did not find a version where this is not listed as a known problem.